# Why am I missing android camera libraries?

Tags: android

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;



CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();



for(int x=0; x < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); x++){
```

Eclipse is complaining about: `import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;`
saying it doesn't exist. Also, `Camera.getNumberOfCameras()` is not showing up as a valid method for Camera class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the android platform version of your project in eclipse. CameraInfo didn't get added to the SDK until API Level 9 (Android 2.3) so in versions older than that, it won't be found.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you set your app on Android 2.3 or greter Exclipse may import the "wrong" library

> import android.graphics.Camera;

instead of

> import android.hardware.Camera;

Sa make sure it is the hardware one for Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); to work...